# Verilog: Register File assignment not updating on clock pulse

Tags: verilog, simulation, register, vivado

I wrote some fairly simple code in Verilog to implement a 32-bit deep, 8-bit wide register file. However, when I actually run a behavioral simulation of the thing the two data-read lines (*rd0_data* and *rd1_data*, respectively) seem to be utterly nonreactive.

I think it's possible I made some mistake in how I built out the inputs and outputs or the "mem" variable, but after fiddling with it for hours I'm sort of lost.

```
module reg_file#(
        parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8,
        parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 5
    )(
        input rst, clk, wr_en,
        input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] rd0_addr,
        input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] rd1_addr,
        input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] wr_addr,
        input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] wr_data,
        output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] rd0_data,
        output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] rd1_data
    );

    integer i; //For the reset operation
    reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] mem [0:31];

    assign rd0_data = mem[rd0_addr];
    assign rd1_data = mem[rd1_addr];

    //Update w. synchronus reset
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst) begin 
            for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) mem[i] <= 0;
        end else begin
            if(wr_en) begin
                mem[wr_addr] <= wr_data;
            end
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Behavioral Simulation output:

[image: Behavioral Simulation]

My test bench code is as follows:

```
module reg_file_tb;
    reg rst, wr_en, clk;
    reg [4:0] rd0_addr, rd1_addr, wr_addr;
    reg [7:0] wr_data;

    wire [7:0] rd0_data, rd1_data;

    // Instantiate the register file (using positional-association for instantiation)
    reg_file dut
    (
        rst, wr_en, clk, rd0_addr, rd1_addr, wr_addr, wr_data, rd0_data, rd1_data
    );

    integer i;

    initial begin
        // Initial values
        wr_en = 1;
        rd0_addr = 5'd0;
        rd1_addr = 5'd0;
        wr_addr = 5'd0;
        wr_data = 8'd255;
        i = 0;

        // Pulse the reset signal for only one clock cycle
        clk = 0;
        rst = 1;
        #20;
        clk = 1;
        #20;
        clk = 0;
        rst = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1)
        begin
            // Sample conditional stimulus: if i equals 4, set the write enable to HIGH
            /*if (i == 32'd4)
            begin
                wr_en = 1;
            end*/

            // Sample conditional stimulus: when i equals 5, change the rd1_addr to 10
            if (i == 32'd5)
            begin
                rd1_addr = 5'd10;
            end


            // Pulse the clock in this for-loop
            clk = 0;
            #20;
            clk = 1;
            #20;

            wr_addr = wr_addr + 5'd1;
            rd0_addr = rd0_addr + 5'd1;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Any helpful guesses or tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you testing it? What results are you actually getting?

Comment: `mem` should only be assigned in one `always` block. Separate is not synthesizible and prone to race conditions in behavioral simulations.

Comment: @Greg: While it's true that that's an issue, the actual question is about simulation.

Comment: @DaveTweed I added the output of my behavioral simulation and the test bench that resulted in it to the post. Sorry for not thinking to include it earlier.

Comment: @Greg Re-coded the always block to reflect your advice. Although it didn't resolve the issue at hand, I appreciate you catching my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally swapped "wr_en" and "clk" when instantiating a module of the register in the test bench. The module itself is fine, I'm just dumb.

Thanks to everyone who looked at it though.